# Freeware Audio Editors (Other than Audacity)

Tags: audio-editor

I have access to Audition most of the time, so I use often use that when I want to edit dialogue, but I'm looking for a simple backup program that I can put on my laptop to use when I can't get in the studio. I've got Logic and Ableton on my laptop for music use but I don't think either is really appropriate and I hate editing audio within a DAW anyway.

Audacity was my first thought as I used and enjoyed it quite a lot several years ago, but on Mountain Lion it is giving me nothing but trouble. I'm sure I could get to the bottom of this over on the Audacity forum but it has made me curious about alternatives. What's out there that's good? I'm looking for freeware/ cheap (sub £20) because I'm broke...

I'm giving the TwistedWave trial version a go and I like it a lot, I'd say all that I'm missing is a spectral view. But it's $80/ £50 and although I'm finding using it to be a better experience than I remember Audacity being, I'm not sure it's worth £50 compared to Audacity's £0.

So yeah, what free or cheap editors are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check ocenaudio. http://www.ocenaudio.com.br/en

It lacks things like volume envelope and support of multichannel wavs, but probably fine for basic editing. I chose Wavosaur over it, but it's not available for Mac.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I'm looking for, I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sound Forge Mac Pro is *servicable*.  If you can find it for cheap it might be worth it. Its still pretty buggy and lacking in features but it's quick to use if youre familiar with the flow.

Answer (score 0):

reaper is free for 60 days and fully functional, so it could work in a pinch.  It's also pretty inexpensive if you're into it.

Comment: I actually have a Reaper license (I seem to be accumulating DAWs without ever buying the one I should really get - Pro Tools), the last time I downloaded it it didn't have a built in audio editor, but that was well over a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

I like Sound Studio on the Mac. It's not too advanced and the filters can be quite buggy but I like that launches fast and makes a great little cutter. It can apply AU filters and has a set of basic filters. £21 in the Mac app store I think.

Comment: This looks decent, I'll be investigating if the free ocenaudio doesn't work out

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to check out this list of audio editors as voted on by our members: http://en.audiofanzine.com/getting-started/editorial/articles/the-top-audio-editors.html

Comment: Link only answers, especially self-promoting ones are generally discouraged.  If you want to include some details that would make the answer useful if the link ever goes dead, that would greatly increase the usefulness of the answer.